# Handle empty response with retrofit and rxjava 2.x

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

When using rxjava 1.x i used to return `Observable<Void>` to handle empty response from retrofit:

```
@POST( "login" )
Observable<Void> getToken( @Header( "Authorization" ) String authorization,
                                       @Header( "username" ) String username,
                                       @Header( "password" ) String password );
```

But since rxjava 2.x won't emit anything with `Void` is there any good practice to handle those empty responses?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Completable.html) was designed for such cases. It available [since](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ru/2015/12/the-new-completable-api-part-1.html) RxJava 1.1.1. From the official docs:

> Represents a deferred computation without any value but only indication for completion or exception. The class follows a similar event pattern as Reactive-Streams: onSubscribe (onError|onComplete)?

So just change your method's return type:

```
@POST("login")
Completable getToken(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                     @Header("username")      String username,
                     @Header("password")      String password);
```

And rewrite your subscriber, e.g.:

```
apiManager.getToken(auth, name, pass)
    ...
    .subscribe(() -> {
        //success
    }, exception -> {
        //error
    });
```

Comment: This solution won't work if the response can be either empty for success or error with body

Comment: Good solution for "fire and forget" requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is:

```
@POST("login")
Observable<Response<Void>> getToken(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                    @Header("username") String username,
                                    @Header("password") String password);
```

Update:
But I would rather use Completable

Answer (score 0):

So the accepted answer is only partially correct.  `Completable` will work in some cases where one and only one emission is expected, however, `Completable` will only emit once, and will not emit after that.  It is similar to `Single` (except we ignore the value being emitted).  `Observable`, on the other hand, can emit **multiple** times.  So if the source observable will emit multiple times, the answer, at least in RxJava2, is to emit something like `Observable<Irrelevant>` (where `Irrelevant` is a static enum/class), or better yet `Observable<Kotlin.Unit>`.

```
public class Source {
    private PublishSubject<Kotlin.Unit> heartbeatOperation;
...
    void getHeartbeats() {
         while(getHeartbeatFromSource() != null) {
             hearbeatOperation.accept(Unit.INSTANCE);
         }  
    }

    public Observable<Unit> heartbeats() {
         return hearbeatOperation.hide();
    }
...
}


public class SourceConsumer {
   @Inject Source source;
...
    void printHearbeats() {
         source.heartbeats()
         .subscribe(unused -> {
             System.out.println("Heartbeat received at " + DateTime.now());
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `Observable<Object>` ?

This is from the official documentation of RxJava 2:

```
enum Irrelevant { INSTANCE; }

Observable<Object> source = Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<Object> emitter) -> {
   System.out.println("Side-effect 1");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);

   System.out.println("Side-effect 2");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);

   System.out.println("Side-effect 3");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);
});

source.subscribe(e -> { /* Ignored. */ }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```