# RxJava2: Alternative to Observable<Void>

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have an API which returns only error/success codes, with no body. With RxJava1 I would have used `Observable<Void>` as the return value for this call.

What can I use for RxJava2? The hint on the Wiki for RxJava2 ([link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)) is not helpful, since I can't change how the API works.

Setup:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to use Observable<Void> ? I use RxJava 2 and Observable<Void>, did not have a single problem.

Comment: Observable of Void sends a  terminal event, I think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41563950/7045114

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `Completable`.

If the operation succeeds, it will emit a successful termination event. If it fails, you can use your own `Exception` subclass to wrap the necessary error codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use an Observable but replace the Void type with an enum type which is defined like this

```
public enum Terminal {
    TERMINAL
}
```

and then use it like this

```
Observable<Terminal>
```

PS: You can name the enum anything you want