# is it possible to mock a retrofit Deferred<Response<T>> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I am wondering if I can do this mock

```
Deferred<Response<Void>>
```

I am new at Kotlin and at mock but I have unsuccessfully made it.

So far I have done this:

I have a client interface:

```
class MyClient {

@POST("/names")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun names(
        @Field("username") username: String
    ): Deferred<Response<Void>>

}
```

On my tests:

lateinit var myClient  : MyClient

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    client = mockk<MyClient>(relaxed = true)
    val response = mockk<Response<Void>>(relaxed = true)
    every { myClient.names(username) }.returns(mockedResponse)

}
```

I've found many posts about Response (like this [Handle empty response with retrofit and rxjava 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558805/handle-empty-response-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-2-x) ) but not really sure how to handle the **"Deferred"**

or some about deferred (cannot implement the answer of this. `async` cannot be resolved in my project

[When using kotlin coroutines, how do I unit test a function that calls a suspend function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118986/when-using-kotlin-coroutines-how-do-i-unit-test-a-function-that-calls-a-suspend)

Is this possible? what am I missing?

The service I am testing:

```
class MyService {

    fun doSomething(username: String) {
       myClient().names(username).await()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us a more complete example of your code? There are several things that won't compile  in your snippets. Where does the `username` come from here: `myClient.names(username)`? Is `doSomething()` in reality a suspend function or where does the needed coroutine come from?

Comment: I just disccovered the poor error handling and while get in the debugger I see the precise error that is more related with other issues I think "An exception occurs during Evaluate Expression Action : Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Can not generate outer receiver value for class.." will need to investigate further, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to return a `Response<Void>` where a `Deferred<Response<Void>>` would be required.

The deferred is basically the result of a job that may have not yet completed. When the deferred `isCompleted`, the result is ready. In your case you most likely want to have a Deferred that is already completed with the response.

To create a Deferred that is already completed with some value you can use the `CompletableDeferred(value: T)` function.

Here is a full example of how to return a completed deferred from a client Mock.

```
interface GithubClient {
    @GET("users/{username}/repos")
    fun listRepos(@Path("username") username: String): Deferred<Response<Void>>
}

class RepoService(val client: GithubClient) {
    suspend fun doSomething(username: String): Response<Void> {
        return client.listRepos(username).await()
    }
}

class GithubClientTests {

    private lateinit var client: GithubClient

    @BeforeTest
    fun setUp() {
        // setup the mocked client
        client = mockk<GithubClient>(relaxed = true)
        val mockResponse = mockk<Response<Void>>(relaxed = true)
        every { client.listRepos(any()) } returns CompletableDeferred(mockResponse)
    }

    @Test
    fun testMockClient() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        // create the service with the mocked client
        val service = RepoService(client)
        val response = service.doSomething("octocat")

        // response is not successful, because we didn't specify any behavior for the mocked response
        assertFalse { response.isSuccessful }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! In this case this works but now I get an exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to retrofit2.Response" is this because the mocked response? it breaks on the line when I call the client on my service in this way ->  myClient.names(username).await()

Comment: Probably the `mockedResponse` object is not of type `retrofit2.Response`.

Comment: I get this error "An exception occurs during Evaluate Expression Action : Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Inconsistent state: expression saved to a temporary variable is a selector
File being compiled at position: mock:///fragment.kt
The root cause was thrown at: ExpressionCodegen.java:286"

Comment: In this case it works perfectly, but unfortunately I am testing over a service that calls the client (as described) and the method inside that service makes a call client.listRepos("octocat").await() and I think that is the problem, somehow the mock there gets crazy :s

Comment: Updated the example again to use an intermediate service.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you're missing an await:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    client = mockk<MyClient>(relaxed = true)
    val response = mockk<Response<Void>>(relaxed = true)
    every { myClient.names(username).await() /* this would return an response instead of deferred */ }.returns(mockedResponse)
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you! but in this case, it works but it tells me "Suspension functions can only be called within coroutine body", any idea what Id have to do to fix it? I moved it to my unit test function @Test fun test() = runBlocking {..} but the problem persists

Comment: yes, you might want to look into runBlockingTest:
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/

Comment: This solution mocks a smaller part of the code. It only mocks the result of the `await()` function. For example if the client code does not call `await()` but `isCompleted` or any other function of the `Deferred`, it will fail.

Comment: Sure, it would fail on ```isCompleted```, but it does solve author's problem - your solution works as well. In this specific case you shouldn't worry about other methods being called. Have a good one!